# When we talk and already have a context, can we omit components such as "the", "of" or "in"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, ellipsis

When we talk and already have a context, can we omit components such as "the", "of" or "in"?

In the examples below, I want to talk about the students of Harvard University only, but I don't want to repeat "the students of Harvard University" because that is too long.

I came up with a few alternatives like these below. Which are acceptable to you?
I guess that with a clear enough context, all of these are correct, right?

> (1) When you were at Harvard University, were **students** asked to do voluntary work?

> (2) When you were at Harvard University, were **the students** asked to do voluntary work?

> (3) When you were at Harvard University, were **the students of the university** asked to do voluntary work?

> (4) When you were at Harvard University, were **the students at the university** asked to do voluntary work?

Comment: Suppose the question had been *When you were at Harvard University, **were students exempt from conscription**?* In *that* case it would be almost 100% certain that with ***no*** article, questioner is asking whether ***all students in the country*** were exempt - but ***with*** the article it would unambiguously be specifically asking about ***Harvard** students*. That same distinction would apply to your own example, but because of the *exact* context, yours is potentially much more ambiguous (there's more chance of the "less likely" interpretation being correct).

Comment: It's hard to imagine any native speaker thinking that if the questioner said ***the students***, but failed to include ***at the university***, he might actually be talking about students at some ***other*** university. But that's basic ***logic***, not really even about ***language*** in general, let alone English semantics or syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Your case "When you were at Harvard University, were students exempt from conscription?" can mean all students in the country. So, in my example (1), "When you were at Harvard University, were students asked to do voluntary work?", "students" can mean the students of Harvard, right? I mean maybe some listeners would understand it that way, right? Maybe I should add "there" after "students", like "When you were at Harvard University, were students there asked to do voluntary work?"

Comment: It's all a matter of ***context*** and [***Grice's Maxims***](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html). We assume that ***When you were at Harvard University*** is contextually relevant to the question. But that relevance could be because of the time *(**when**)*, in which case it could easily be asking about students in general, across the country. OR it could be more about the place *(**Harvard**)*, in which case it's probably asking about ***those*** students. In a real-world context this might be obvious anyway, but you could certainly disambiguate using "students there".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The materials you provided helped me a lot and have enabled me to understand the subtle differences more. Thank you :)

Comment: I quite like the first example in the top answer to the linked question: *I adopted two cats. **Cats / The cats,** long ago, were worshipped as gods.* Including the article *(**the**)* there would be "quirky", but if you're happy to accept that doing so is at least "syntactically valid" (but it has to mean ***my*** cats were worshipped) then I think you've got the key message from Grice's Maxims (which imho should be taught to everyone who wants to learn a foreign language; you can learn your *native* language without being aware of these maxims, but they're important for "foreign" languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of 1-4 are grammatically valid, and fluent speakers and writers use such language all the time.  (1) is potentially ambiguous, as several comments have pointed out. "students" could me "students at Harvard University", or "all students everywhere", or some other group of students. changing it to "the students", as in (2), clarifies that and makes the meaning of "students at Harvard University" more explicit. There is no significant change in meaning between (2), (3), and (4). Additional context might further clarify (1), but the addition of "the" is a very quick and easy way to make the intention clear.